# How to solve for inverse of $f({x}) = {x} \cdot \lceil\log_{10}{(x+1)}\rceil$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In searching for a way to solve a problem on Kattis found [here](https://open.kattis.com/problems/nnnnn), I found that the length of a string composed of a positive decimal integer $n$ concatenated with itself $n$ times (e.g. $1, 22, 333, 4444, 55555$), $len(n)$, is $len({n}) = {n} \cdot \lceil\log_{10}{(n+1)}\rceil$. The problem given, however, is to find $n$ given $len(n)$. How could I approach solving this problem?

Comment: -1 with no comment? Poor form.

Comment: +1 because I completely agree with your comment. Downmarks should be explained, or else they are nothing more than mindless bullying. Perhaps they felt that you are cheating by getting assitance in solving the problem? But since it doesn't seem to be any active contest, and the problem has been solved many times already, I don't see that as an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the encrypted message is $x = an$, where $a = \lceil\log_{10}{(n+1)}\rceil = \lfloor\log_{10} n\rfloor + 1$. But for the time being, let's ignore the rounding and pretend that $a = \log_{10} n$.

So $\log_{10} x = \log_{10} a + \log_{10} n = a + \log_{10} a$. I.e., the value of $a$ is just a little less than $\log_{10} x$, and is also a factor of $x$. This should allow it to be found very quickly, and therefore also the plaintext message $n = \frac xa$.